# Referencing a cell in a query transformation to create a reverse running total

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have been working on this for several days now and am having no luck in figuring it out, but feel like I am very close.

In Excel, I am trying to create a reverse running total for a budget by referencing a cell which can be modified or updated.

The only way I have been able to make this work so far is by hard-wiring the starting amount in manually. this is what I want, except every time we receive money I have to change the starting amount manually again.

```
= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Q4Rec"]}[Content][QT4_Received]{0}
```

I used this to break down one of my input tables into queries that result in singular numeric values. (The table sums all of the revenue received into annual and quarter) How do I how to reference the new single-quantity queries in my previously built queries to conduct the transformation. I keep getting null values.

Comment: If the above formula results in a  value then use the query name for that query in place of the number you hard coded elsewhere. If that is not working then post your real code in your question

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I'm a bit of a novice with Excel power query. I was able to make it work once I figured out how to reference the query from within a new query. haha #"queryname" Thanks helping me decipher the question I was trying to get to.